# How to create a pull down to close element using jQuery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As an experiment I've been trying to come up with a simple way to create a modal (essentially just a div) that I can pull down on mobile device to close. by close I mean remove from the screen/view.

To explain this, here's an angular version example: [here](https://codepen.io/warrino/pen/yOybaB)

I need to find a way to do this using javascript or jQuery.

I know Hammerjs is something that I can use but I haven't been able to find an easy/simple way to do this!

Also, I know hammerjs has some issues with vertical swipe/scrolling!

here's a javascript example but doesn't exactly give me the result that I am looking for:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
document.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

var xDown = null;                                                        
var yDown = null;

function getTouches(evt) {
  return evt.touches ||             // browser API
         evt.originalEvent.touches; // jQuery
}                                                     
                                                                         
function handleTouchStart(evt) {
    const firstTouch = getTouches(evt)[0];                                      
    xDown = firstTouch.clientX;                                      
    yDown = firstTouch.clientY;                                      
};                                                
                                                                         
function handleTouchMove(evt) {
    if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
        return;
    }

    var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
    var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

    var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
    var yDiff = yDown - yUp;
                                                                         
    if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
        if ( xDiff > 0 ) {
            /* right swipe */ 
            alert();
        } else {
            /* left swipe */
        }                       
    } else {
        if ( yDiff > 0 ) {
            /* down swipe */ 
        } else { 
            /* up swipe */
        }                                                                 
    }
    /* reset values */
    xDown = null;
    yDown = null;                                             
};
```

Can someone please advice on this?

Comment: From your description it kind of feels like a drag event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drag_event